# What DNS Changes should I make?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, mx-record, ip-address

I'm moving a website to a new server. But I only want to change where the website is pointing to. So basically example.com and www.example.com. I'm afraid if I change the A record for @, mail will stop working for this website.

Right now everything is pointing to 13.119.XX.XX. I want to point just the website to the 67.91.XX.XX ip-address that the staging A record is pointing at.

Answer (score 2):

Your email (POP3/IMAP/SMTP) works with MX records, not A records. So if you change the A records, the only thing of concern would be making sure the A record for 'mail' points to the correct email web interface.

Comment: Only `SMTP` (that is MUA) uses `MX` records. POP and IMAP certainly do not. And more precisely, MUAs query for MX records first and use them if available, and if not then go back to A/AAAA.

Comment: IPv4 is legacy now so there is not only `A` in the DNS but also `AAAA` to map names to IP addresses!

Answer (score 1):

1. change www cname "@" to example.com
2. make and A record for
   example.com that points to the new IP

> ```
> A     example.com. 167.99.XX.XX
> cname www         example.com.
> ```

Comment: @patrick-mevzek I have done it in this format so it would mimic the system that he is working on

Comment: How do you know exactly which system is he working on?

Comment: @patrick-mevzek I think he is using Plesk or cpanel to edit his DNS there was an image of it yesterday

Comment: Standard zonefile notation works everywhere and is understood everywhere. I do not think it warrants your edit rollback, besides the other problem in formatting or content in your answer, which I tried to address to make it nicer, but I won't battle for it. You are also badly obfuscating IP addresses.

Comment: @patrick-mevzek I’m just explaining why, I’m not fighting with you on it I know that your format is correct if you will edit it manually, but he is going to use a form to enter the values.